# Recursive Function in Clojure Fails Assertion

Tags: string, random, recursion, clojure

The following is a recursive function:

```
(defn make-control-data [it  alphabet] 
  {:pre [(integer? it) (pos? it)]}
  (let [shuffled-alphabet-string (reduce str (shuffle alphabet))] 
   (if (zero? it) 
       shuffled-alphabet-string  
       (str shuffled-alphabet-string (make-control-data (dec it) alphabet)))))
```

It should take an integer (`it`) that specifies the number recursive calls and a string list of letters, e.g., `["a" "b"]`. It should return a randomly ordered string of length `it*length(alphabet)` using all the letters from the alphabet. If `it = 2` and the alphabet = `["a" "b"]` the function should yield a random string of length `(* 2 (count ["a" "b"])) = 4` using all the letters from the alphabet `["a" "b"]`.

It breaks the pre condition `(pos? it)`, and the returns a string of length `(it+1)*length(alphabet)`.

Can anyone see what's wrong?

Comment: It is advisable to use higher order functions over explicit recursion as shown in the answer by @amalloy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is apparently willing to accept `it`=0, so your precondition should not forbid that input. Zero is your recursive base case, not an error. If I were putting a precondition on this function (though I wouldn't), it would be `[(not (neg? it))]`.

If I were writing this from scratch I wouldn't bother with all the recursive noise, but simply:

```
(defn make-control-data [num alphabet]
  (apply str (repeatedly num #(apply str (shuffle alphabet)))))
```

Comment: I see, (pos? it) returns false when it=zero. Thanks.

Comment: @sesanker Yep, zero is not positive. It's non-negative, though. [Relating to or designating a quantity greater than zero](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/positive)

Answer (score 0):

This is a correct function using recursion:

```
 (defn make-control-data [it  alphabet]
   {:pre [(integer? it) (not (neg? it))]}   
   (if (zero? it) "" 
       (str (reduce str (shuffle alphabet)) (make-control-data (dec it) alphabet))))
```

`(make-control-data 2 ["a" "b" "c"])` returns `"bcacab"` and

`(count (make-control-data 2 ["a" "b" "c"]))` returns 6.

Also, the following works:

```
(defn make-control-data [it  alphabet]     
  (if (= it 1) (reduce str (shuffle alphabet))
      (str (reduce str (shuffle alphabet)) (make-control-data (dec it) alphabet))))
```

with one less recursion step than the previous function. Although, the pre conditions and the recursion are unnecessary, I'd appreciate other, better ways, to implement this function recursively.